# Unable to call a method from RecyclerView adaptor class

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have created a recyclerView -

```
public class PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>


 playerAdapter = new PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter(this,cursor, playerDataSet);
        playerRecyclerView.setAdapter(playerAdapter);
```

It all works fine, but I created the following method:

```
public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    // Always close the previous mCursor first
    if (pCursor != null) pCursor.close();
    pCursor = newCursor;
    if (newCursor != null) {
        // Force the RecyclerView to refresh
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But when I try to call it from the activity that is linked to the adapter, it does not find it:

```
 new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                //Do nothing, we are not moving anything
                //But maybe we can let the user arrange their list?
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                long id = (long) viewHolder.itemView.getTag();
                removePlayer(id);
                playerAdapter.swapCursor(getAllPlayers());

            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(playerRecyclerView);
    }
```

Swap cusor is red and in the adapter it shows the message it is never used.

I am trying to follow:

[https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/blob/student/Lesson07-Waitlist/T07.05-Solution-AddGuests/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/waitlist/GuestListAdapter.java](http://%20https://github.com/udacity/ud851-Exercises/blob/student/Lesson07-Waitlist/T07.05-Solution-AddGuests/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/waitlist/GuestListAdapter.java)

But I am not sure what I am missing?
Everything else works fine, I can swipe, it loads the details. All good just calling this method for some reason does not work.

Comment: You should post complete code of adapter and activity class. So one can tell correct way to call method.

Comment: `playerAdapter` should be defined as `PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter playerAdapter;` Not like `RecyclerView.Adapter playerAdapter;`.

Comment: @ADM thanks, this has fixed it. Can you please post it as an answer so I can mark it correct

Comment: Its working fine here when I have tried your code of swapCursor.. 
Can you send complete code of activity in which you are using it and the adaptor as well ?..

Answer (score 0):

please check your player adapter is getting null value.

because swapCursor method access after defining playeradapter object.

```
if(playerAdapter!=null){
playerAdapter.swapCursor(getAllPlayers());     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code for declaration of `playerAdapter`.
It should be as :-

```
PlayerListRecyclerViewAdapter playerAdapter;
```

**InsteadOf**

```
RecyclerView.Adapter playerAdapter;
```